# Lubuntu updating via the command line

Tags: command-line, updates, lubuntu

To update Ubuntu, I periodically use `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Is this or is this not advisable for Lubuntu on a low-spec machine (single core 2.66 GHz, 1GB memory)? Will use of it cause Lubuntu to "bloat" to the point of defeating the original design intentions of Lubuntu.

Comment: It's just upgrading.. The same as upgrading any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to update your system; the Software updater, the Synaptic Package manager, and apt-get.  I believe all three will yield the same results, so there is no danger of "bloating" your system.